# Are there any statistics plotting likelihood of getting a call with an offer against time since the last interview?

Tags: interviewing

I am curious as to whether there is a correlation between the amount of time you have to wait before the company contacts you, and whether the answer will be a positive or a negative one.

Comment: Given that a rather large fraction of companies never bother to give any sort of reply to a candidate that they're not extending the offer to, there must be a negative correlation.

Comment: Probably, yeah there is a correlation. But it would be next to useless as each company will have their own process, and each position advertised would vary according to interview schedules

Comment: In my personal experience, there is no correlation. For example, I received a call asking me if I am still interested in accepting a job six months after I had interview.

Comment: Such a measurement would be effectively pointless for an individual-- what would you gain with such knowledge, how could that help you? A better measure of whether you _personally_ get an offer is your understanding of how well the interview went.

Answer (score 1):

Logically the shorter the period the more likely it is to be positive.  If you are their first choice they are going to offer you the job and leave everyone else hanging until you accept or decline.  If you decline then they contact their second choice and leave everyone else hanging until they accept or decline.  And on and on.

However it may take them several weeks to decide on their first choice let alone second and third choices.

Comment: Does it really take them several weeks to decide on their first choice? Surely these things take a matter of hours to review a couple hours of interviews

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine   Some decide immediately, some take ages.  It's kind of a matter of corporate culture and circumstance.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine if you have a hiring committee and each member has their own agenda, then it can take ages to decide on their first choice.  If the committee selects your first choice over mine and your first choice is hired, then you win and I lose.  If the committee selects your first choice over mine and your first choice has found another job, then you have not won and I have not lost.  We continue the battle about second choice.